# How to verify authorization for RESTful api?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest

My application is using AngularJs as a front-end framework and NodeJs, ExpressJs , as a back-end framework. They can contact each other by using RESTful service. The application allows a user to be able to manually create a new role with custom accessible systems for that role.

Whenever a $http request has made by AngularJs, `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE`, it need to be verified whether a current user has a role contained the required sub-systems or not.

```
app.post('/api/v1/budgets/upsert', auth.requiresLogin, auth.requiresRoleSubSystem([10, 11, 12, 13]), budgetCtrl.upsertBudget);
// to access this api link, user need to have role contained at least one of a system in the array [10, 11, 12, 13]
```

As you can see, I have a middleware, `auth.requiresRoleSubSystem(subSystemIds)`, to do so. It works without any problems, however, I must manually set the array of sub-system ids required to access each api link.

It's very frustrated and would be difficult if the sub-system id has changed. I have been thinking some possible solutions but all the solutions are almost the same, need to be manually set. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you try $http interceptor? For example: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/, put your logic in interceptor

Comment: Thanks @ABOS, it's very useful for the front-end side. However, I still have to manually verify authorization on the back-end side as I described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use constants instead of the id numbers? So you could easily modify the ids in a single config file. You could even generate that config file on the server.

<strike>Afaik. `app.post` is a request from the client to the server, so it is a client side code. Client side code should not contain auth logic. REST services return only the authorized links. I guess you are building a traditional JSON based webapplication instead of a REST service.</strike>

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you explain which constants should be used instead of id numbers? Actually, `app.post` is on a server side, sit in the Express's route, which's listening to the request made from client-side and verifying authorization before doing any action.

Comment: @LVarayut Ohh then that part is okay. I would use a central role object `{editor:10, admin: 11, ...}` and use `auth.requiresRoleSubSystem([roles.admin, roles.editor, ...])`. So by id changes you have to change only a single file. Another enhancement to give unique name to each of the roles and generate the roles object using the database: `{name: id}`. A further enhancement to store the endpoint - requiredRoles records in the database, and modify them from admin pages, but that is usually not a requirement.

Comment: I think that your suggestion would work in case that the roles were predefined and would have never been changed. However, in my case, a user has the ability to manually add a new role, and choose which systems should be allowed for the particular role. In other words, `{editor:10, admin: 11, ...}` would be set by the user. So, in the Express's route, I can't put `auth.requiresRoleSubSystem([roles.admin, roles.editor, ...])` because I would never know what is the name of the roles input by the user, `admin`, editor, etc.

Comment: @LVarayut If I understand well the endpoint - roles pairs are in the database and the user - roles pairs are in the database as well, and you want to have a user -> allowed endpoints query. What's the problem, why did you implement it manually?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Yes, `Users`, `Roles`, `Systems` are stored in my database. The concept is that a user holds some roles, then, the roles contain some systems. So, whenever the user makes a request, assume that `/api/v1/budgets/upsert` requires a role which must contain `system` named `Creating budgets`, I must verify that which roles the user are holding, and then, at least one role must contain `Creating budgets` system. If so, the user will be allowed to access this Api.

Comment: What I'm using is `auth.requiresRoleSubSystem([10, 11, 12, 13]`  to tell that only the roles containing one of these system's ids will be allowed. The problem is that manually setting  `10, 11, 12, 13`  would be such a bad idea.

Comment: @LVarayut Try something similar I already described, either naming the systems, or having endpoint - system_id pairs in the database would help. The only problem with the latter one, that by changing the endpoint you would have to change the database as well. So I think the best solution is using unique role name and unique system name in the code, which do not change and which you should check whether they are defined. This way you can filter typos as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the Role collection a code as @inf3rno said:

```
var Role = new Schema({ 
code: {type: String, index:true},
name: String,
data: {},
active: boolean
});
```

This way, the code is an indexed string constant (for example ROLE01) and then you will be able to map this value all over your system despite the _id is changing.

For example, if your user seems like this:

```
User {
name: String,
roles: [role._id]
}
```

Just try to save it like this:

```
User {
name: String,
roles: [role.code]
}
```

Hope it helps!!